# How to confirm Multi-AZ for Postgres and Aurora Postgres in Amazon AWS

Tags: postgresql, amazon-web-services, amazon-rds, high-availability, availability-zone

I want to use MultiAZ for Postgres and Aurora Postgres databases.

In the Postgres database configuration tab it shows:

> Multi-AZ
>
> yes
>
> Secondary Zone
>
> ap-south-1a

But I can't find any reader in the db list overview.

Whereas in the Aurora Postgres it shows on the cluster:

> Availability
>
> Multi-AZ
>
> 2 Zones

**AND** there is a reader in another availability zone without any read access in the db list overview.

It's a bit confusing. Do I have enabled MultiAZ in both?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> It's a bit confusing. Do I have enabled MultiAZ in both?

Mutli-AZ in RDS and Aurora works differently. In Aurora, your fail-over instance is one of the readers. Thus it does not have a dedicated Multi-AZ option.

In contrast, in RDS, multi-AZ **readers are not used** for multi-AZ. Instead, RDS creates a special db instance, called [standby replica](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/Concepts.MultiAZ.html) (this is not read replica). The main purpose of this standby instance is to be your fail-over in case primary instance fails. Also the standby can't be used for reading. You can't connect to it.

Comment: Thank you. This means I can use the MultiAZ reader in Aurora (Postgres) as a real reader? Meaning without losing the MultiAZ availability.

Comment: @steros Yes, but it must be in different AZ as the writer.